# Merge and lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, merge, orm

Hi I hope you can help me with this question:

```
Student
...
@ManyToOne
Mentor


Mentor
...
@OneToMany
Student
```

Is there any difference in using merge on a student when:

Mentor is lazy:
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE))

Mentor is eager:
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE))

Comment: CascadeType.ALL very bad idea. Read my answer. Do you want to delete the Mentor of a whole class of students just because one Student has quoted ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First nothing will happened when merging if you are not cascading.  In your example you have not specified Cascade.Merge therefore your merge operation will not be cascaded.

Lets assume that you have cascading. If your entity is not initialized which may happen if you relationship is Lazy the cascading will not be propagated over the non initialized collection.

In your particular case following the JPA specification the default behavior of ManyToOne is EAGER.

In case it is EAGER the entity will be checked if it is dirty, in case it is dirty the merge will be cascaded further

**One more thing. CascadeType.ALL on ManyToOne is a bad idea.** Because if you DELETE one entity on the MANY side this will trigger a delete of the parent object. I believe you really dont want this. I strongly recommend you to remove the CascadeType.All

Comment: It's a sample code, so even with cascade.merge the merge will not happen if the entity or collection is lazy initialized right ?

Comment: The ManyToOne side is EAGER by default, unless marked as Lazy.

Comment: I marked as LAZY : "Mentor is lazy: @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.MERGE))"

Comment: @GionJh The difference between Lazy and EAGER is that if it is Lazy if it is not initialized(never touched) the Cascade will not be propagated. If it is initialized(touched) it follows the same algorithm as if it is EAGER. Which means that if will check if the Entity is dirty(modified) and if dirty(modified) the operation will be propagated, if it is not dirty the operation will not be propagated. Do you have questions in regards of this comment ?

Comment: Ok , that's not true with remove operation right ? it is only true with merge ?

Comment: When it comes to delete there is no need for Dirty check. Because if you delete the parent you dont care if the child is modified or not.

Comment: You also have one more case for delete - which is delete orphan. This is when you delete all childs and it automatically deletes the parent if the parent is not related to any child any more.

Comment: I meant with remove operations the child entity/entities will be remove even when they are lazily initialized right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The lazy child elements will be removed no matter if they are initialized or not. A delete SQL query will be generated if they are marked with CascadeType.DELETE

Comment: Thank you a lot I have one more thing to ask:  in the case an entity or collection or entities is lazily initialized and we drop a relation from parent to child , we set studet.setMentor(null) for example, will the entity manager track this when we merge?

Comment: On the OneToMany side if you set it to null nothing will happen, because this is not the owning side. If you set it on the ManyToOne side the element where you set it to null the foreign key will be set to null. In other words it will no longer have parent. Usually in the database though you have foreign key constraints and most of the times it will not be possible at all. But now that depends on if you have constraint or not.

Comment: so this happens regardless of the fact the the entity or collection is eagerly or lazily initialized ?

Comment: When it comes to the Lazy Eager, no because the parent entity is not really interested in the referenced entity. It is only interested to what value it should set its foreign key column. This is if you dont have cascading defined.

Comment: is it true even when the owning side is tha oneToMany side ?

Comment: If the owning side is OneToMany all the deletes updates you do on the collection will be reflected on the database.  If you remove an element , the element will be removed, if you add an element element will be added. If you call collection.clear() everything will be removed and so on... All the updates in Hibernate are happening through the Owner of the relationship. The question who is the owner is very important.

Comment: Yes, so supposing i have the onetomany as the owner and a collection is lazily initialiazed : the merge will not be cascaded but the entitymanager will still track the relationships so if I remove an element from the collection and then merge it will be reflected on the db ?

Comment: It will be reflected to this extend that its foreign key will be set to null. There will not be a delete statement but only an update statement. If you want a delete as well you need to have cascading.

Comment: Just one small remark, the comment above is correct if you have a link table the link table gets updated. I am a bit unsure that an update statement is executed if a link table is not present. My common logic though is saying that it should set the foreign key to null. I guess this one you should test yourself.

Comment: @GionJh  You can not have the OneToMany side owning the relationship and at the same time have ManyToOne. If you define your OneToMany as collection owner you can not attach to it a ManyToOne, it becomes unidirectional. But now we are getting very far away from the original question.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that the field that it  is set to NULL is the foreign key on the non owning side, the OneToMany side right ? (i the case we do not have a link table)

Comment: As I said if you have a link table, the link table will be updated. If you dont have I dont know.

Comment: Ok my Guess is Yes , I will test. Thank you very much for your Time. BTW if you have a book or documentation where I can learn more aboutb this can you suggest it to me ?